# MySQL - trigger called twice causes deadlock

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, innodb, deadlock

I have a table with millions of rows and I have to use count it divided by groups.

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `group_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

so calls I made very often are

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE group_id=XXX`

But unfortunately MySQL is really slow (>10 sec for one call) when counting in tables with dozens millions of rows.

So I decided to create a new table to keep counters only:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_stats` (
    `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` INT(11) NOT NULL,
)
```

where I can keep current counters and make sure it's up to date using triggers.

So I have a triggers for insert/update/delete, here's example of insert one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `customers_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `customers` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE customer_stats
    SET
      `value` = `value` + 1
    WHERE
      customer_stats.group_id = NEW.group_id;
END
```

and it works fine for most cases, but on high load (dozens of calls per seconds) I got deadlocks.

```
2016-09-21T20:14:30.639907Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB: Transactions deadlock detected, dumping detailed information.
2016-09-21T20:14:30.639926Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB:
*** (1) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 10390, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2059, OS thread handle 140376644818688, query id 85330 test_test-php-fpm_1.test_default 172.19.0.12 root updating
UPDATE customer_stats
SET
  `value` = `value` + 1
WHERE
  customer_stats.group_id = NEW.group_id;
2016-09-21T20:14:30.639968Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB: *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 85 page no 3 n bits 72 index customer_stats_key_group_id_unique of table `test`.`customer_stats` trx id 10390 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 21; hex 637573746f6d657264657461696c735f636f756e74; asc customerdetails_count;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 2: len 6; hex 000000002890; asc     ( ;;
 3: len 7; hex 34000002341224; asc 4   4 $;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000666; asc    f;;

2016-09-21T20:14:30.640302Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 10391, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
10 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2057, OS thread handle 140376513820416, query id 85333 test_test-php-fpm_1.test_default 172.19.0.12 root updating
UPDATE customer_stats
SET
  `value` = `value` + 1
WHERE
  customer_stats.group_id = NEW.group_id;
2016-09-21T20:14:30.640334Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

2016-09-21T20:14:30.640850Z 2057 [Note] InnoDB: *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

It exists only on high load and I wonder if there is some easy way to change the trigger to make sure, that they don't try to execute that `UPDATE customer_stats` in the same time, as this is causing deadlock. So two customer record must be created in the same time to raise deadlock.

Tables and system of triggers I have is a little bit more complicated, but I tried to simplify it as much I can to explain you what is my problem.

Comment: Have you tried an index on `group_id`?

Comment: @Solarflare yes, there is an index on that column in both tables

Comment: *"So two customer record must be created in the same time to raise deadlock"*  That isn't what a deadlock means.  Two at the same time is not the problem.  Transactions don't deadlock unless each of them holds a lock the other one needs, which suggests that you are doing multiple inserts within a single transaction. Can you confirm that? And, if so, why are you doing that?  Also it would be easier to explain if you hadn't removed some of the status messages.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot here the whole deadlock message http://pastebin.com/yK2vhEsh, query is a little bit more complicated, as I'm not using "customer_stats" table, but "table_stats", because it's not one table I have a counter for, but more than one and I'm using one table to keep all counters in one table only.

Comment: and logs of deadlock for simplified version of trigger (as presented in example above): http://pastebin.com/bWcjhEap
What my thoughs are that deadlock is because I'm trying to update same row in table_stats table in separate sessions, so they both get `UPDATE SET value = 100+1` and it's because a deadlock is, as there is no easy increment function in MySQL and it's value based, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I just added new stored procedure with exacly the same code (different from yours) and called it when needed without trigger and there were no deadlocks anymore. I've had ~500 trigger executions per second (~500 updates on the same cell per second). So just removing trigger worked for me. Maybe this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

You need a composite `INDEX(key, group_id)`, in either order.

Let's simplify the trigger:  Step 1:  `VALUES` is simpler than a `SELECT`:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE originalGroupId INT;
    SET originalGroupId = NEW.group_id;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_stats(`key`, value, group_id)
        VALUES ('customers_count', 0, originalGroupId);   -- line changed
    UPDATE table_stats
    SET
      table_stats.`value` = table_stats.`value` + 1
    WHERE
      table_stats.`key` = "customers_count"
      AND table_stats.group_id = originalGroupId;
END
```

Step 2:  Use IODKU.  At this point, that needs to be `UNIQUE(key, group_id)`, in either order.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE originalGroupId INT;
    SET originalGroupId = NEW.group_id;
    INSERT INTO table_stats(`key`, value, group_id)
        VALUES ('customers_count', 1, originalGroupId)  -- note 1 not 0
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            `value` = `value` + 1;
END
```

Steps 1 and 2 make it run faster, thereby decreasing the frequency of deadlock.

Step 3:  Deal with deadlocks!  They are *not* totally preventable.  So, plan on repeating the entire transaction whenever a deadlock occurs.

Comment: This is not a solution. !!

Comment: @Ouroboros - Not all deadlocks can be eliminated.  My Answer tries to mitigate the problem.  At that point, the cost of replaying a Rolled back transaction will be acceptable.

Comment: why and how the secondary keys can cause problem needs to be clearly communicated. I'll try to write down an answer where we faced similar issue

Comment: @Ouroboros - ((1) The transaction processing locks rows that _might_ be involved.  In some situations, extra rows (or gaps) get locked.  (Sorry, I don't have a useful example.) (2) The big benefit is that an index may allow the query to finish faster, thereby "getting out of the way" faster, thereby _decreasing_ the likelihood of a deadlock (or "lock wait timeout").  That is, a secondary key won't _cause_ a problem, but it might _avoid_ a problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I found out what was the problem.

I tried to simplify the problem to show you here, but it looked like after I made it simpler - the problem was not existing anymore.

My original trigger was:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE originalGroupId INT;
    SET originalGroupId = NEW.group_id;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_stats(`key`, value, group_id)
    SELECT 'customers_count', 0, originalGroupId;
    UPDATE table_stats
    SET
      table_stats.`value` = table_stats.`value` + 1
    WHERE
      table_stats.`key` = "customers_count"
      AND table_stats.group_id = originalGroupId;
END
```

and I looks like deadlock is caused by `INSERT IGNORE` or variable as when I deleted it - it started to work without any issues. Thanks!